# Docker: Deploying app on a cluster

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to deploy app in a cluster according to this tutorial:

https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#deploy-your-app-on-a-cluster

However, I got stuck in a simple problem. I am supposed to copy the file docker-compose.yml I created to the swarm manager myvm1’s home directory (alias: ~) by using the docker-machine scp command:

```
docker-machine scp docker-compose.yml myvm1:~
```

If I use this code, I am getting this error:

```
command-line line 0: garbage at end of line; "Barua\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\myvm1\\id_rsa".
lost connection
exit status 1
```

I exactly do not know what's wrong I am doing. Am I supposed to copy docker-compose.yml file in the myvm1 directory? It will be very great if you can explain a bit how can I solve it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: if you enter this command in bash, you must escape the ~ so that the local shell does not expand it.

Comment: @Anik Barua - you need to copy files to a docker from host machine?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP I have to copy the to the host machine... that is "docker-compose.yml" file need to be copied in virtual Machine's (myvm1) home directory.

Comment: @Henry If I escape the ~ , then myvm1 is being created instead of creating docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and did some research. The issue seems to lie in the fact that your username is separated with a space. There is no current fix to this.

Comment: You are right, I had one space in the user name. After I removed it, everything worked perfectly, thanks :)